# Make those functions ie9 compatible

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-9

I tried those functions in ie9 ( well ie10 set as ie9 emulation ).
in those functions "doc" is a svg document root element.
addSvgTransform

```
  /**
   * Add a <g> element that envelop all SCG elements and makes the viewbox transformMatrix descend on all elements
   */
  function addSvgTransform(doc, matrix) {
    matrix[3] = matrix[0] = (matrix[0] > matrix[3] ? matrix[3] : matrix[0]);
    if (!(matrix[0] !== 1 || matrix[3] !== 1 || matrix[4] !== 0 || matrix[5] !== 0)) return;
    // default is to preserve aspect ratio
    // preserveAspectRatio attribute to be implemented
    var el = document.createElement('g');
    while (doc.firstChild != null) {
      var node = doc.firstChild;
      el.appendChild(node);
    }
    el.setAttribute('transform','matrix(' + matrix[0] + ' ' + matrix[1] + ' ' + matrix[2] + ' ' + matrix[3] + ' ' + matrix[4] + ' ' + matrix[5] + ')');
    doc.appendChild(el);
  }
```

Failing point:
el is a document.element.
ie9 doesn't wan't to append to this kind of node any other node from our SVG and it doesn't want to do the contrary , appending this node to the Svg doc directly.
our doc variable doesn't have a createElement method.
Purpouse of this function is to add a 'G' element between root of the doc and all other elements

**this is solved** 
doing var el = document.createElement('g'); ==> : var el = doc.ownerDocument.createElement('g');

parseUseDirectives

```
  function parseUseDirectives(doc) {
    var nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName('use');
    while (nodelist.length) {
      var el = nodelist[0],
          xlink = el.getAttribute('xlink:href').substr(1),
          x = el.getAttribute('x') || 0,
          y = el.getAttribute('y') || 0,
          el2 = doc.getElementById(xlink).cloneNode(true),
          currentTrans = (el.getAttribute('transform') || '') + ' translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')',
          parentNode;

      for (var j = 0, attrs = el.attributes, l = attrs.length; j < l; j++) {
        var attr = attrs.item(j);
        if (attr.nodeName === 'x' || attr.nodeName === 'y' || attr.nodeName === 'xlink:href') continue;

        if (attr.nodeName === 'transform') {
          currentTrans = currentTrans + ' ' + attr.nodeValue;
        }
        else {
          el2.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue);
        }
      }

      el2.setAttribute('transform', currentTrans);
      el2.removeAttribute('id');
      parentNode = el.parentNode;
      parentNode.replaceChild(el2, el);
    }
  }
```

This function is failing because doc doesn't have a doc.getElementById method.

Edit: the problem here is that there ia nodesByID method of ie9. To use it i have to specify that id attribute is of type ID or XS:ID.
To do that i have to add a xsd or dtd schema if i understood good.
So i would like to add this notation before parsing the doc.
What i should write?

```
<xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID" />
```

Where? How? Any ideas, help?

Comment: Ok first is done. 
from : var el = document.createElement('g');
to : var el = doc.ownerDocument.createElement('g');